# SVN can't update or upgrade working copy - errors E155036 & E155016

Tags: svn, svnx

First - I'll admit SVN really confuses me. Newbie!

I've got a Wordpress plugin I've been working on and wanted to post an update. It's gone smoothly in the past, but it's been a LONG time since I've done anything with it and I had to update my SVN Client (on mac Mavericks) and I am now at 1.8.11.

If I try to update my project I get the error that I need to update my working copy:

```
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: The working copy at '/path/to/file'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.8.11 (r1643975)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

But if I try to upgrade (as it tells me) the process stalls and I get an error there as well:

```
svn: E155016: Insufficient NODES rows for '/path/to/file/.svn/tmp/wcng/trunk/css/images'
```

I'm trying to find my way using svnX and Terminal and am at a loss how to proceed. Any suggestions would be welcome...

Matthew

Comment: Never seen that one during an upgrade before... what version was your working copy coming from? Worst case scenario just check it out to a new location and then move your changed files into the new working copy.

Comment: I think it was version 1.6 - what came with Apple OS Lion.

Comment: So - checking out into a new location is giving me an error too... "svn: E155037: Cleanup with an older 1.7 client before upgrading with this client." I guess that means I need to downgrade to 1.7 and then cleanup?

Comment: Thanks prodigitalson! I sorted it out. Restarted, ran clean up and I was able to check out into a new location without any more issues. Back up and running.

Answer (score 1):

For any future searchers like me:

This error can be caused by old extraneous SVN revert files in your working copy, such as `.svn-revert` or `.svn/dir-prop-revert`. Just delete any such files (they're not used for anything) and then you should be able to finish your `svn upgrade`!

Take a look at the official bug report for more details:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-4043